# NSPredicate with Boolean

Tags: arrays, core-data, nspredicate

I'm quite new to CoreData in Swift. I wanted to create a NSPredicate in which I could pull any object that had a boolean property set as true. How might I do this? I did somethings as follow but they didn't seem to work.

```
"any property = 1"

"any property = YES"
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 you can use the following format:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "boolAttribute == %@", NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true))
```